# ng-click doesn't enter function itself

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm trying to refresh a captcha code by clicking on a button. however it doesn't enter the function itself. am i missing something? here's my controller.js code:

```
$scope.goCaptcha = function()
{
console.log('entered');
var alpha = new Array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4','5','6','7','8','9','0');

var i;
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var a = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
    var b = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
    var c = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
    var d = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
    var e = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
    var f = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
    var g = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
}
var code = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + ' ' + c + ' ' + d + ' ' + e + ' ' + f + ' ' + g;

document.getElementById("main-captcha").value = code
}
```

and here's my html code:

```
 <label class="item item-input" id="login-input3">
     <input type="text" readonly id="main-captcha">
    <button type="submit" class="button button-small" ng-click="goCaptcha()">Refresh</button>
 </label>
```

Comment: looks good, but maybe your template has not the correct controller assigned to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work. You might be missing `ng-controller="yourCtrlName"` in HTML. Or check for any other silly mistakes.

Working snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.goCaptcha = function() {
    console.log('entered');
    var alpha = new Array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0');

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      var a = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
      var b = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
      var c = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
      var d = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
      var e = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
      var f = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
      var g = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
    }
    var code = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + ' ' + c + ' ' + d + ' ' + e + ' ' + f + ' ' + g;

    document.getElementById("main-captcha").value = code
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <label class="item item-input" id="login-input3">
     <input type="text" readonly id="main-captcha">
    <button type="submit" class="button button-small" ng-click="goCaptcha()">Refresh</button>
 </label>
</body>

</html>
```